# collection_select does not display text_method in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, select, collection-select

I am building a small project but it has taken an error.
I want to use a selection box to select my district (District model has 2 columns: id, name)
Here is my code

```
 <%= f.select :district_id, options_for_select(District.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }), {prompt: 'Select District'}, class: "form-control" %>
```

But when i run it, the name of district is not display.
[image]
[image]

Amount of record District in my database is 9 records. You  can see that the amount of options is correct, but the name of district has disappeared.

My District table
[image]

#### **Update**: I has fixed my error succesfully by using

```
 <%= f.select :district_id, options_for_select(District.all.collect {|p| [ p[:name], p.id ] }), {prompt: 'Select District'}, class: "form-control" %>
```

I have just change district.name => district[:name]
Could anyone explain this for me.
Thanks you all.

Comment: are you sure names are not empty ?

Comment: Try  `<%= f.select :district_id, District.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'Select District'}, class: "form-control" %>`

Comment: @Pavan the same result @@

Comment: Try this <%= f.select :district_id, options_for_select(District.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }) %>

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.collection_select :district_id, District.all, :id, :name, {prompt: 'Select District'}, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: thank you, i has tried it, but it has the same error.

Comment: i tried your suggest before, but the district names is still not displayed.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.